# using wp_query to return posts w/ comment count > 0

Tags: wp-query, comments

I've looked at numerous examples of wp_query and can't figure this out.  If the thing I was comparing were a meta value then I could to a meta query, but apparently you can't do a compare with a non-meta value?

This is what I thought it would work:

```
$commentpost = new WP_Query( array( 'key' => 'comment_count',
                                'value' => '0',
                                'compare' => '>',                                                    
                                'orderby' => 'comment_count',
                                'order' => 'DESC', 
                               ) );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wrote a patch the other night to be able to query posts based on amounts of comments, please test it over here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28399

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `WP_Query` class has the native possibility to `orderby` the `comment_count`, it doesn't have the same to query based on those. But when we look at the `posts`-table, we can see that there isn't much we need to alter

```
ID | post_author | post_date | post_date_gmt | post_content | post_title | post_excerpt | post_status | comment_status | ping_status | post_password | post_name | to_ping | pinged | post_modified | post_modified_gmt | post_content_filtered | post_parent | guid | menu_order | post_type | post_mime_type | comment_count
```

So the thing we could do, is intercept the query and modify the `WHERE` clause inside the `posts_where`-filter.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;
/* Plugin Name: (#121083) Query WHERE comment count not is 0 */

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse121083WhereCommentCountNotNull' );
function wpse121083WhereCommentCountNotNull( $where )
{
    // Don't fire more than once:
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    # @TODO Add abort clauses/cases here

    return "{$where} AND {$GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts}.comment_count != 0";
}
```

You still have to fill in the bits like cases where you don't want to intercept the query. Keep in mind, that it's not tested.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm a bit new to all this.  I'm not knocking your answer, but I'm using a filter currently to return posts only within the past 20 days. WP3.7 allows for a better method as I understand it with that.  Is using filters like this considered a kludge?  Is it considered best practice to just write out a full SQL statement for what you want rather than appending stuff to a wp_query via a filter?

Comment: You could write a separate custom SQL statement as well, but then you'd simply drop the main query result that runs anyway and add another query on top. So best practice would be to intercept the main query - if it's the main query. If it's not the main query, you can do whatever helps you to reach your goal (as long as it _doesn't_ involve the use of `query_posts()`).