# Query posts with more than 20 comments

Tags: wp-query, comments

Is there a simple way to query posts with a comment count above a certain number?

For example, I want to list only posts that have more than 20 comments.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',

    'posts_per_page' => 25,

    // Something like this
    'comments_query' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 20,
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>=',
        ),
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WP_Query` does not currently support querying by the `comment_count` field, but there is a proposed patch for this functionality. See [Trac ticket #28399](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28399).  *Update: #28399 has been fixed and should land in version 4.9*

In the meantime, here is a workaround based on information from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121083/using-wp-query-to-return-posts-w-comment-count-0) post which will alter the `where` clause of a query and allow you to restrict the number of posts returned based on their comment count.

Add this code to your `functions.php` or to a plugin:

```
// Modify the where clause to include only posts with 20 or more comments
function wpse_post_where_comment_count( $where ) {
    // Don't fire more than once:
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    return "{$where} AND {$GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts}.comment_count >= 20";
}
```

Add this code to your template:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_post_where_comment_count', 10, 1 );
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 25,
] );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
```